# Загрузка изображений JS

Tags: javascript, html, img

Ситуация такая: Есть скрипт который загружает файл на сервер, возможно ли сделать так чтобы при выборе файла не надо было нажимать кнопку загрузить, он автоматом чтобы грузился.

JS:

```
function hideBtn(){
   $('#upload').hide();
   $('#res').html("Идет загрузка файла");
}

function handleResponse(mes) {
   $('#upload').show();
   if (mes.errors != null) {
      $('#res').html("Возникли ошибки во время загрузки файла: " + mes.errors);
   }   
   else {
       $('#res').html("Файл " + mes.name + " загружен");   
   }   
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" target="hiddenframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="hideBtn();">
   <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" />
   <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
<div id="res"></div>
<iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px"></iframe>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на событие "change" повесь обработчик, и когда будет изменение поля с типом "file", тогда и грузить на сервер. В общем через onchabnge

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: Я могу написать как сделать, но лучше почитайте про событиия, это очень важная и хорошая штука, и пригодится ВЕЗДЕ. input.onchange = function(e){}..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще простого. Кнопка Загрузить в форме нам больше не нужна.

```
<form id="imgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" />
</form>


// как только загрузится страница
$(document).ready(function() {
  // повесить следующий обработчик на input c id userfile
  $("#userfile").on('change', function(e) {
    //выпольнить запрос 
    $("#imgForm").submit();
  });

});
```

Comment: а как я пойму что оно действительно ушло на сервер и загружено? раньше кнопка загрузки мне об этом сообщала

Comment: @Павел, понять Вы сможете это только обработав за сервере, потом сервер вернет ответ, не знаю куда у вас там и если все ок то отобразите превью загруженной картинки или текст что все ок.

Comment: Если посмотреть на то решение которое я нашел, то там при успешной загрузке файла на сервер, выводится сообщение. Загружен ли файл или нет, такое возможнео будет организовать в вашем коде, и как жэто возможно сделать?